# App rejected for Designed for Families due to stability issues

Tags: android, console, publishing, stability

I received this email from Google:

"App status: Your app has not been accepted into Designed for Families, and     the update is not live on Google Play.

Eligibility issues:

- During testing we experienced stability issues with your app and were unable to successfully evaluate it for the Designed for Families program. Please make sure your app behaves predictably at runtime and does not crash, hang, or display error messages, and resubmit."

I have tested my app in the simulator, emulator, and in a Samsung phone and it works fine. Did anyone else had this issue with Google and how did you solve it? I'm at a loss and feel like I'm on a dead end. Please help.

Comment: Please check the pre release report in your playstore console. You will most probably find the videos of their tests. You can figure out what went wrong by watching them.

Comment: Ok I see in the report the app has 3 warnings. 2 of which relates to same issue where the app stalls a bit more than 700ms upon going into a game scene with a number of images. 1 is about colour text contrast ratio. The report does not have any crash or error messages. Should an app be really squeaky smooth before getting approved? I'm going to try to fix these warnings and hopefully it goes well.

Comment: 700 ms delay means your app has ANR issues. Google allows upto 150 ms I guess (Please cross check the number as I am not sure too) but beyond that it is not acceptable as it causes resource abuse.